# Windows batch file: move files that older than 10 days and the filename without a specific string

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am creating a batch file for task scheduler in Windows 7.
The logic is searching files in a folder, if the filename without a specific string, and it's older than 10 days, move the file to another folder.

I've tried so many commands but cannot achieve this (combine the findstr and date condition). And as I am quite new to batch commands. Could anyone please give me some scripts or advice?

Here is what I wrote for moving the files without specific string in the filename, but dont know where to put the date condition:

```
for /r %Path_new% %%H in ("*.avi") do (echo "%%~nH" |findstr /i "_connID=">nul ||((move /y "%%H" "%Path_achieve%" ) && (echo %date% %time% - %%H has been moved >> Log4BB.txt)) )
```

And if I put a date condition in a script, it will be like this but cannot get the files with a specific string in the filename:

```
forfiles /p %Path_new% /m *.avi /d -%Day_noconnid%  /c "cmd /c if @fname like '*_connID=*' (echo @path will be moved)" >> Log4BA.txt
```

For robocopy, I don't know how to specify the files that i want to move. My scripts as below:

```
for /r %Path_new% %%G in ("*.avi") do (^
    echo "%%~nG" |findstr /i "_connID=">nul ||(^
        robocopy "%Path_new%"\"%%~nG%%~xG" "%Path_achieve%" /maxage:10 /mov)^
) >> Log4BC.txt
```

Comment: Could you please be more specific on your specifications.   Sure would like to know where you found this in any help file for any batch file command: `cmd /c if @fname like '*_connID=*`.  Are you trying to find files with the string **_connID** in the file name?

Comment: Actually, this script like '*_connID*' was just testing if I can use it. But it cannot work.

Comment: What I wanted to find are files have a name without _connID= in the string. And then if the file's modified date is older than 10 days, then move the files to another folder.

Comment: Use Robocopy instead.  Use the `/minage` and `/xf` options.

Comment: I tried robocopy, it doesn't work. it's in the for loop. and the source I am using %%H which is the full path of the file.

Comment: You would not use robocopy inside the FOR command. You can use ROBOCOPY by itself to accomplish this task. `robocopy C:\soure C:\destination *.avi /minage:10 /xf  *_connid*`

Comment: But if I don't put in the FOR loop, how could I only move these files? I dont want to move all the files. Only the .avi files without the "_connID=" in the filename

Comment: What don't you understand about the `/XF` option.  EXCLUDE FILES!  From the help: **eXclude Files matching given names/paths/wildcards**.

Comment: Thanks Squashman! I didn't know that as I just started writing batch this week. And just read the help guide for Robocopy. And it's working now! Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I got the answer. Robocopy has a /XF that allows me to put the condition for filename.

```
robocopy %Path_new% %Path_achieve% *.avi /mov /xf "*_connID=*.avi" /minage:%Day_noconnid% /log+:"Log4B.txt"
```

Working very good now. Thanks Squashman